# How to do Query optimization in SQL Sever?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I am trying to speed up my execution time. What's wrong with my query. What is the better way to do query optimization.

TransactionEntry has 2 Million records

Transaction Table has 5 Billion Records

Here is my Query, If I remove the **TotalPrice** column, I am getting results at **10sec**

```
--Total Quantity
SELECT 
    items.ItemLookupCode,sum(transactionsEntry.Quantity) Quantity,sum(transactionsEntry.Quantity*transactionsEntry.Price) TotalPrice

into 
    ##temp_TotalPrice
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        TransactionNumber,StoreID,Time
    FROM   
        [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction]
    WHERE 
        Time>=CONVERT(datetime,'2015-01-01 00:00:00',102) and Time<=CONVERT(datetime,'2015-12-31 23:59:59',102)
    ) transactions

left join [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry] transactionsEntry
ON transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber=transactions.TransactionNumber and transactionsEntry.StoreID=transactions.StoreID

Left join [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item] items
ON transactionsEntry.ItemID=items.ID

Group By items.ItemLookupCode
Order by items.ItemLookupCode
```

If I execute this(above one) query, it produce the result in **22 seconds**. It's too long

When I execute the subquery alone(Below one). It's taking 11 seconds

```
(
SELECT 
    TransactionNumber,StoreID,Time
FROM 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction]
WHERE 
    Time>=CONVERT(datetime,'2015-01-01 00:00:00',102) and Time<=CONVERT(datetime,'2015-12-31 23:59:59',102)
) transactions
```

> I have created one index for `TransactionEntry Table` that
>
> 1. `TransactionNumber,StoreID,ItemID,Quantity,Price`
>
> One index for `Transaction Table`
>
> ```
> `Time,TransactionNumber,StoreID`
> ```
>
> One Index for `Item Table`
>
> ```
> `ID`
> ```

Execution Plan
[image: Execution Plan Image]

> Clustured Index of TransactionEntry is taking 59% cost. That column_Name is `AutoID`

Comment: In what kind of database would `Transaction` have 2,500 times more rows than `TransactionEntry`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff one transaction number from `Transaction Table` will have many products in `TransactionEntry`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is for SQL 2005 or above version. If its for SQL 2000, then instead of `CTE` you can have a `temp` table with proper index.

Also Since you were getting the values from `[HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry]` and `[HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item]`, why Left Join is used?
Avoid sub queries. I have re framed the query. Please check and let me know whether it improved the performance

```
;WITH transactions
AS
(
    SELECT 
        TransactionNumber,StoreID,Time
    FROM   
        [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction]
    WHERE 
        Time>=CONVERT(datetime,'2015-01-01 00:00:00',102) and Time<=CONVERT(datetime,'2015-12-31 23:59:59',102)
)
SELECT 
    items.ItemLookupCode,sum(transactionsEntry.Quantity) Quantity,sum(transactionsEntry.Quantity*transactionsEntry.Price) TotalPrice
into 
    ##temp_TotalPrice
FROM [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item] items INNER JOIN [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry] transactionsEntry
ON transactionsEntry.ItemID=items.ID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM transactions WHERE transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber=transactions.TransactionNumber and transactionsEntry.StoreID=transactions.StoreID)
Group By items.ItemLookupCode
Order by items.ItemLookupCode
```

Comment: A subquery versus CTE makes absolutely no difference for query performance.

Comment: Agree. But as per his comment the sub query was not impacting the performance.

Comment: @GopakumarN.Kurup your query doesn't make any difference. After I changed index as Abishek mentioned, it's executing in 22 sec. when I run your query it's taking 32 sec.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query, simplified and formatted a bit (the subquery makes no difference):

```
select i.ItemLookupCode,
       sum(te.Quantity) as quantity,
       sum(te.Quantity * te.Price) as TotalPrice
into ##temp_TotalPrice
from [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction] t left join
     [HQMatajer].[dbo].[TransactionEntry] te
     on te.TransactionNumber = t.TransactionNumber and
        te.StoreID = t.StoreID left join
     [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Item] i
     on te.ItemID = i.ID
where t.Time >= '2015-01-01' and
      t.Time < '2016-01-01'
group by i.ItemLookupCode
order by i.ItemLookupCode;
```

For this query, you want indexes on `Transaction(Time, TransactionNumber, StoreId)`, `TransactionEntry(TransactionNumber, StoreId, ItemId, Quantity, Price)`, and Item(Id, ItemLookupCode)`.

Even with the right indexes, this is processing a lot of data, so I would be surprised if this reduced the time to a few seconds.

Comment: Did not understand why we need a LEFT JOIN here. What is the use of that?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Quantity and price is not from ITEM Table. I have to do `Quantity * Price` from **Transaction Entry** Table. So Why should I create  index in ITEM to Quantity and Price?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - about the indexes suggested I had some doubt, would the below suggested ones be any difference to the ones suggested by you `TransactionEntry(TransactionNumber, StoreId, ItemId) INCLUDE(Quantity,Price)` and `Item(ID) INCLUDE (ItemLookupCode)`. Also the I guess the index suggestion on `Item` might be having some issue.

Comment: @Abhishek your index is correct. After i created. It executes in 22 sec. But I need little bit more.

Comment: @Abhishek . . . You are correct.  I had the columns in the wrong table.  You can either `include` the columns in the select or use them as keys.

Answer (score 0):

This query is taking to much time because three times the entry is inserted into the temporary table which increases the time. if we insert the record into a another table and thn call it or make it as a cte. It decreases the cost.